# Creating an instance of an interface itself in Android

Tags: android

Here is code

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //...
  }
});
```

where `setOnClickListener` looks like:

```
public void setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener l) { /* compiled code */ }
```

However, what's `new View.OnClickListener()` itself? It turns out this is an interface:

```
//View.class
public static interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(android.view.View view);
  }
```

That is, here `btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() ....` I create an instance of  the interface. No, this is not the instance of a class which **implements** this interface.

How is it possible to create an instance of an interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. It is a [Anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements the interface. The onclick that goes after is the implementation of onclick.

Try to do it like this:

```
View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    //...
  }
};
btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

This may look more clear.